# Shading different regions of the graph based on time period

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a graph using `ggplot2` that takes dates on the x-axis (i.e 1000 years ago) and probabilities on the y-axis. I would like to distinguish different time periods by shading regions of the graph different colors. I stored the following dates here:

```
paleo.dates <- c(c(13500,8000), c(13500,10050) ,c(10050,9015), 
c(9015,8000), c(8000,2500), c(8000,5500), c(5500,3500), c(3500,2500), 
c(2500,1150), c(2500,2000), c(2000,1500), c(1500,1150), c(1150,500))
```

I would like to take a time period, say 13500 to 8000, and color code it until it overlaps with another date, such as the third entry.

I am using the ggplot2 cheatsheat, and I attempted to use `aes(fill = paleo.dates)`, but this does not work as it is not the same length as my dataset. I was also thinking of using `+ geom_rect()` to manually fill the areas, but that does not seem very elegant, and I am not sure it will even work.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "until it overlaps with another date"? Doesn't the second entry also overlap with the first one? What happens in these overlaps? It should be easy to change the shade based on where the date falls within a set of mutually exclusive ranges.

Comment: Yeah the dates are kind of all over the place in the beginning, I was thinking of making some sort of gradient color to represent the overlaps, but not sure how to do that either. How would I change the shade in a mutually exclusive range? using geom_rect() isn't very satisfying, so if there is a clever way that would be neat.

Comment: Create a column that identifies the range for each row (e.g., using case_when), and fill based on that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a subset of period. In this case I created a `sub` vector to transform into a factor to facilitate the fill.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(paleo.dates = seq(500, 13000, 100),
                 p = runif(n = length(seq(500, 13000, 100)),
                           0, 1))

sub <- data.frame(sub = rep(1:(13000/500), each = 5))
sub <- sub %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:nrow(df))
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(period = sub$sub,
                period = as.factor(period))
ggplot2::ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = paleo.dates, y = p, 
               fill = period,
               col = period), 
           show.legend = F, stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]